# Why is onShowPress() not called?

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have fairly complicated layout that includes a `recyclerview` with `cardview` nested in it. On one of my activities, I have all the details of a single `cardview` element. I have a nested class that implements `OnScaleGestureListener` and `OnGestureListener` to scale and move the views that are in the activity. All that is working as intended but the `onShowPress()` is not called at all. As a result I could not get long click on my view.

Here is my class implementation:

```
public class MyScaleGestures implements View.OnTouchListener, ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
        private View view;
        private ScaleGestureDetector gestureScale;
        private float scaleFactor = 1;
        private boolean inScale = false;
        float dX, dY;

        public MyScaleGestures(Context c){ gestureScale = new ScaleGestureDetector(c, this); }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View touchedview, MotionEvent event) {
            //scale the view
                this.view = touchedview;
                gestureScale.onTouchEvent(event);
            switch (event.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                                .y(event.getRawY() + dY)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                        break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = (scaleFactor < 1 ? 1 : scaleFactor); // prevent our view from becoming too small //
            scaleFactor = ((float)((int)(scaleFactor * 100))) / 100; // Change precision to help with jitter when user just rests their fingers //
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            inScale = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) { inScale = false; }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Log.e("clicked?", "I think so");
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_alert_title));
                    alert.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_alert_message));
                    alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnaddImage.setClickable(false);
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.delete_decline), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return false;
        }

        //@Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float x, float y) {
            float newX = view.getX();
            float newY = view.getY();
            if(!inScale){
                newX -= x;
                newY -= y;
            }
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point p = new Point();
            d.getSize(p);

            if (newX > (view.getWidth() * scaleFactor - p.x) / 2){
                newX = (view.getWidth() * scaleFactor - p.x) / 2;
            } else if (newX < -((view.getWidth() * scaleFactor - p.x) / 2)){
                newX = -((view.getWidth() * scaleFactor - p.x) / 2);
            }

            if (newY > (view.getHeight() * scaleFactor - p.y) / 2){
                newY = (view.getHeight() * scaleFactor - p.y) / 2;
            } else if (newY < -((view.getHeight() * scaleFactor - p.y) / 2)){
                newY = -((view.getHeight() * scaleFactor - p.y) / 2);
            }

            view.setX(newX);
            view.setY(newY);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try returning false in other events . May be another delegate(Listener) catches your event

Comment: @Nepster, I did like what you said. Unfortunately, the listener is simply ignored.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and detect the onpress event ? Is an onShowPress method is scaledetector's own abstract method ?

Comment: Try to call the super class first in your onShowPress method in the first line by adding `super.onShowPress(motionEvent);` .

Comment: The class is nested in my main activity. So super doesn't recognize onShowPress.